# Let users create custom blade templates

Tags: php, strings, html, laravel, laravel-blade

**Problem**: I need to let my web-app users *create their own blade layouts*. The content shall change based on what is in the database, hence their layouts should become dynamic in nature. With only the content parts changing and layout different as customized by the user.

**Solution:** Save the user's layout code into a database column.

```
//Then In controller
//$templateInDatabase = content from database column, which contains user's custom layout code

$content = View::make('final',compact('data'));
$token = "<meta name='_token' content='" . csrf_token() ."'";
$scripts = View::make('final_scripts',compact('data'));

$view = str_replace_first("<%content%>", $content, $templateInDatabase);
$view = str_replace_first("<%token%>", $token, $view);
$view = str_replace_first("<%scripts%>", $scripts, $view);

return $view;
```

The user shall be required to include the three `<%X%>` tags in the template code.
The benefits are that there is no server side code execution, hence added security. Cache problems minimize as the `final` and `final_scripts` blade templates can be cached. But the string replacements add extra effort.

How bad is this solution?

Comment: Layout means you want the user to customized header footer or entire page layout.? If any layout has been saved then do you want that layout should be used by other pages of application as well.?

Answer (score 2):

## Ensure template contains required tags

> The user shall be made to include the three `<%X%>` tags in the template code.

It is difficult to know since the code to save the templates is not present - Maybe that code already validates that those tags are included (and perhaps exist only once) but if not then it might be wise to ensure that validation exists before a template can be saved.

## Blade templates can execute plain PHP blocks

> *The benefits are that there is no server side code execution, hence added security.*

[Laravel 5.3 was released on August 23, 2016](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#History), slightly more than a month after this code was posted. Maybe you are aware of this already- starting with [the documentation for version 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#php), there has been mention of the `@php` directive “to execute a block of plain PHP within your template”.

## `$token` is an unterminated HTML `<meta` tag

The assignment for `$token` is:

> ```
> $token = "<meta name='_token' content='" . csrf_token() ."'";
> ```

One would expect that tag to be terminated:

```
$token = "<meta name='_token' content='" . csrf_token() ."'>";
```

## Three function calls could be simplified with one

Obviously it is a micro-optimization and might likely require additional lines of code, it would be more efficient to call `str_replace()` with arrays for the first two parameters instead of calling `str_replace_first()` three times. This would allow for `$view` to be assigned only once and thus not over-written. Bearing in mind that `str_replace_first()` would only replace the first occurrence, the template should only contain one instance of each custom tag anyway, lest any redundant tags persist and not be interpreted correctly.